# Where do I put my driver files for JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to an oracle xe 11g server (11.2) and when I attempt to run my program I get the error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I have installed ojdbc7 and it is in the foulder with both my connect.class and connect.java files. What am I doing wrong? Sorry this is remedial, new to oracle.

```
 public static void main(String args[]){  
        try{  
        //step1 load the driver class  
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");



    //step2 create  the connection object  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");  

    //step3 create the statement object  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

    //step4 execute query  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
    while(rs.next())  
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

    //step5 close the connection object  
    con.close();  

    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.. I needed to add the driver to my build path.